# (iOS Swift) Fetching record from Core Data return fatal error or nil

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-data

I'm starting to code with Swift for iPhone apps, i'm facing this rather confusing obstacle that for some of you might be trivial. I keep getting error message that the record is either `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` or `nil`, but when i check the .sqlite the record is there

Let me walk you through

**The name of my .xcdatamodeld is ReviewerApp.xcdatamodeld, the same as my app name ReviewApp**
[ReviewerApp.xcdatamodeld](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqt2S.png)

**My class name is `Users` and my Entity name is `User`**

[Class: Users, Entity: User](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgGco.png)

**My Attributes (username, email, password) are all `type: String`, with `properties: optional`**

**Users.swift**

```
import Foundation

import CoreData

@objc(Users)

class Users: NSManagedObject {

    // Insert code here to add functionality to your managed object subclass

   @NSManaged var username: String?

   @NSManaged var email: String?

   @NSManaged var password: String?


}
```

**The `saveUser()` function in `signUpController.swift`**

```
func saveUser() {

    // create an instance of our managedObjectContext
    let moc = DataController().managedObjectContext

    // we set up our entity by selecting the entity and context that we're targeting
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("User", inManagedObjectContext: moc) as! Users

    // add our data
    entity.setValue(usernameTxtFld.text, forKey: "username")
    entity.setValue(emailTxtFld.text, forKey: "email")
    entity.setValue(passwordTxtFld.text, forKey: "password")

    // we save our entity
    do {
        try moc.save()
        //user.append(entity)
        print("saved")
    } catch {
        fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
    }

}
```

**The `fetch()` function in `SignInController.swift`**

```
let moc = DataController().managedObjectContext    
let userFetch = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "User")           
do {    
    let fetchedUser = try moc.executeFetchRequest(userFetch) as! [Users]    
    print(fetchedUser.first!.username!)               
 } catch {
    fatalError("Failed to fetch person: \(error)")  
 }
```

Everytime i save the user registration process, the record is saved in core data. But everytime i am trying to fetch it:

1. by: print(fetchedUser.first!.username!) , the message in the console is `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`
2. by: print(fetchedUser.first?.username) , the message in the console is `nil`

Thank you very much for the help, in advance

Answer (score 0):

First I would highly suggest you not to using '!' anywhere in your code as it will crash your app (only for static resources). You can use 'if let XXX = YYY as? [...]' to safely cast whatever you want...

Then you are probably not saving anything in your Database. How is your model? Yours Users class must be adequate to the model you built otherwise it won't work (which is a pain), also in your model you have to give your entity its class (in the 'class' field just below 'parent entity').

Also you don't have to use 'entity.setValue(usernameTxtFld.text, forKey: "username")' as you casted your entity beforehand. You could just 'entity.username =usernameTxtFld.text'.

If I didn't help, try to also add the xcdatamodel please.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, actually the system suggested me to add '!'. The saving process is fine, i open the .sqlite and the data is there. My ``Class name is set Users'` and ``Entity is set User``. I have updated my question with some specifics and images

Comment: Well I guess they might be a misspell somewhere... maybe the managedContext? (do you have several?) otherwise everything seems correct to me.

Comment: Yes, exactly what i thought. Everything seems correct to me too, sadly we don't have developer tools to walk us through like what firefox or chrome have when we are developing web. This is new thing for me, and it's confusing...

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed out on

```
 let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("User", inManagedObjectContext: moc)

fetchRequest.entity = entityDescription

do {
    let fetchedUser = try moc.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
      print(fetchedUser.first!.username!)
} catch {
    let fetchError = error as NSError
    print(fetchError)
}
```

The method returns an array of results if the fetch request is successful. Note that Core Data always returns an array if the fetch request is successful, even if we expect one result or if Core Data didn't find any matching records.

For more information and clarification visit -

```
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-and-swift-managed-objects-and-fetch-requests--cms-25068
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and i actually have read the link before asking this question. I added ``let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()`` to declare the ``fetchRequest`` variable. But when i tried to print ``fetchedUser.first!.username!`` the error message was ``Value of type 'AnyObject' has no member 'username'``

Answer (score 0):

The case is closed. There is some problem with the DataController.swift. It was called to save the data, but when it is called to fetch the data it somehow pointing to different place. So, what i did was

1. Not use the DataController.swift anymore
2. Equipped my AppDelegate.swift with // MARK: - Core Data Saving support for saving context, because i didn't set my app with including core data in the beginning

   func saveContext () {

   ```
       if managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
           do {
               try managedObjectContext.save()
           } catch {
               // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
               // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
               let nserror = error as NSError
               NSLog("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
               abort()
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. I changed my saving function to

   func saveUser() {

   ```
       let appDelegate =
           UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

       let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

       //2
       let entity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Users", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext) as! Users


       //3
       entity.setValue(usernameTxtFld.text, forKey: "username")
       entity.setValue(emailTxtFld.text, forKey: "email")
       entity.setValue(passwordTxtFld.text, forKey: "password")

       //4
       do {
           try managedContext.save()
           //5
           message = "Signing up is successful"
           alertMessage(message)

       } catch let error as NSError  {
           print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
       }


   }
   ```
4. And changed my fetch function to

   func fetch() {

   ```
       let appDelegate =
           UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

       let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

       //2
       let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Users")

       let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "email == %@ AND password == %@", emailTxtFld.text!, passwordTxtFld.text!)
       fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
       //3
       do {
           let results =
               try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
           user = results as! [Users]

           let row = user.count

           if row > 0 {

               message = "You're signed in"
               //self.performSegueWithIdentifier("signInIdentifier", sender: self)
           }else{

               message = "Email & password combination is incorrect!"
           }

           alertMessage(message)

       } catch let error as NSError {
           print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
       }


   }
   ```